# Merging csv files using python and pandas (overlapping rows)

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I try to update stock data in one csv file with new rows in another. Because of the way I retrieve this data, the rows do partly overlap. The basic stock file contains (simplified example):

```
Mar 08, 2016    9692.82     9688.47     9785.05     9617.69     95.75M  -0.88%
Mar 07, 2016    9778.93     9764.08     9803.73     9690.00     78.15M  -0.46%
Mar 04, 2016    9824.17     9800.86     9899.11     9742.76     93.45M  0.74%
Mar 03, 2016    9751.92     9807.06     9808.52     9709.68     85.25M  -0.25%
Mar 02, 2016    9776.62     9780.84     9837.11     9695.98     106.45M     0.61%
Mar 01, 2016    9717.16     9482.66     9719.02     9471.09     99.54M  2.34%
Feb 29, 2016    9495.40     9424.93     9498.57     9332.42     93.79M  -0.19%
```

This file should be updated with the data from a second file:

```
Mar 11, 2016    9831.13 9672.05 9833.90 9642.79 118.96M 3.51%
Mar 10, 2016    9498.15 9697.64 9995.84 9498.15 177.50M -2.31%
Mar 09, 2016    9723.09 9700.16 9838.95 9679.19 100.90M 0.31%
Mar 08, 2016    9692.82 9688.47 9785.05 9617.69 95.75M  -0.88%
Mar 07, 2016    9778.93 9764.08 9803.73 9690.00 78.15M  -0.46%
```

The code I use to try to achieve the update looks like that:

```
existingquotes = pd.read_csv(filenames_quotes[i], parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True, header=None, delimiter='\t')
newquotes = pd.read_csv(filenames_upd[i], parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True, header=None, delimiter='\t')
existingquotes.update(newquotes)
mergedquotes=existingquotes
print mergedquotes
```

The output looks like this:

```
           0        1        2        3        4        5       6
0 2016-03-11  9831.13  9672.05  9833.90  9642.79  118.96M   3.51%
1 2016-03-10  9498.15  9697.64  9995.84  9498.15  177.50M  -2.31%
2 2016-03-09  9723.09  9700.16  9838.95  9679.19  100.90M   0.31%
3 2016-03-08  9692.82  9688.47  9785.05  9617.69   95.75M  -0.88%
4 2016-03-07  9778.93  9764.08  9803.73  9690.00   78.15M  -0.46%
5 2016-03-01  9717.16  9482.66  9719.02  9471.09  99.54M    2.34%
6 2016-02-29  9495.40  9424.93  9498.57  9332.42  93.79M   -0.19%
```

There is a gap between 2016-03-01 and 016-03-07. If I use

```
existingquotes.update(newquotes), overwrite=False)
```

the update looks like the original csv. Appreciate any help!

Comment: maybe it's because of not matching indicies?

Comment: could you please post post expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first add parameter `index_col=[0]` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for set first column to `Datetimeindex`, then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by union of both indexes and last use function [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) for filling `NaN` by values of `DataFrame` `newquotes`:

```
print existingquotes
                  1        2        3        4        5       6
0                                                              
2016-03-08  9692.82  9688.47  9785.05  9617.69   95.75M  -0.88%
2016-03-07  9778.93  9764.08  9803.73  9690.00   78.15M  -0.46%
2016-03-04  9824.17  9800.86  9899.11  9742.76   93.45M   0.74%
2016-03-03  9751.92  9807.06  9808.52  9709.68   85.25M  -0.25%
2016-03-02  9776.62  9780.84  9837.11  9695.98  106.45M   0.61%
2016-03-01  9717.16  9482.66  9719.02  9471.09   99.54M   2.34%
2016-02-29  9495.40  9424.93  9498.57  9332.42   93.79M  -0.19%
print newquotes
                  1        2        3        4        5       6
0                                                              
2016-03-11  9831.13  9672.05  9833.90  9642.79  118.96M   3.51%
2016-03-10  9498.15  9697.64  9995.84  9498.15  177.50M  -2.31%
2016-03-09  9723.09  9700.16  9838.95  9679.19  100.90M   0.31%
2016-03-08  9692.82  9688.47  9785.05  9617.69   95.75M  -0.88%
2016-03-07  9778.93  9764.08  9803.73  9690.00   78.15M  -0.46%

existingquotes = existingquotes.reindex(existingquotes.index.union(newquotes.index))
print existingquotes
                  1        2        3        4        5       6
0                                                              
2016-02-29  9495.40  9424.93  9498.57  9332.42   93.79M  -0.19%
2016-03-01  9717.16  9482.66  9719.02  9471.09   99.54M   2.34%
2016-03-02  9776.62  9780.84  9837.11  9695.98  106.45M   0.61%
2016-03-03  9751.92  9807.06  9808.52  9709.68   85.25M  -0.25%
2016-03-04  9824.17  9800.86  9899.11  9742.76   93.45M   0.74%
2016-03-07  9778.93  9764.08  9803.73  9690.00   78.15M  -0.46%
2016-03-08  9692.82  9688.47  9785.05  9617.69   95.75M  -0.88%
2016-03-09      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN
2016-03-10      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN
2016-03-11      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN
```

---

If overlapping values are different in both `DataFrames`, you can add:

```
existingquotes.loc[existingquotes.index.intersection(newquotes.index),:] = np.nan
```

But in this sample are the same, so it can be omited.

---

```
print existingquotes.combine_first(newquotes)
                  1        2        3        4        5       6
0                                                              
2016-02-29  9495.40  9424.93  9498.57  9332.42   93.79M  -0.19%
2016-03-01  9717.16  9482.66  9719.02  9471.09   99.54M   2.34%
2016-03-02  9776.62  9780.84  9837.11  9695.98  106.45M   0.61%
2016-03-03  9751.92  9807.06  9808.52  9709.68   85.25M  -0.25%
2016-03-04  9824.17  9800.86  9899.11  9742.76   93.45M   0.74%
2016-03-07  9778.93  9764.08  9803.73  9690.00   78.15M  -0.46%
2016-03-08  9692.82  9688.47  9785.05  9617.69   95.75M  -0.88%
2016-03-09  9723.09  9700.16  9838.95  9679.19  100.90M   0.31%
2016-03-10  9498.15  9697.64  9995.84  9498.15  177.50M  -2.31%
2016-03-11  9831.13  9672.05  9833.90  9642.79  118.96M   3.51%
```

Instead `combine_first` you can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
print existingquotes.fillna(newquotes)
                  1        2        3        4        5       6
0                                                              
2016-02-29  9495.40  9424.93  9498.57  9332.42   93.79M  -0.19%
2016-03-01  9717.16  9482.66  9719.02  9471.09   99.54M   2.34%
2016-03-02  9776.62  9780.84  9837.11  9695.98  106.45M   0.61%
2016-03-03  9751.92  9807.06  9808.52  9709.68   85.25M  -0.25%
2016-03-04  9824.17  9800.86  9899.11  9742.76   93.45M   0.74%
2016-03-07  9778.93  9764.08  9803.73  9690.00   78.15M  -0.46%
2016-03-08  9692.82  9688.47  9785.05  9617.69   95.75M  -0.88%
2016-03-09  9723.09  9700.16  9838.95  9679.19  100.90M   0.31%
2016-03-10  9498.15  9697.64  9995.84  9498.15  177.50M  -2.31%
2016-03-11  9831.13  9672.05  9833.90  9642.79  118.96M   3.51%
```

Comment: OP wanted: "This file should be updated with the data from a second file:" so i guess `existingquotes.update(newquotes)` after reindexing would update existing values. It's nice solution with `df.index.union()`

Comment: @MaxU, thank you, I modify solution if in real data is necessary update `existingquotes` from `newquotes`.

Comment: That looks very good, will try that as soon I am back at my machine. To clearify: the overlapping data indeed is identical.

Comment: thank you both for answering my very first stackoverflow question :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, it worked like a charm. The final code looks like this:

```
existingquotes = pd.read_csv(filenames_quotes[i], index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True, header=None, delimiter='\t')
newquotes = pd.read_csv(filenames_upd[i], index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True, header=None, delimiter='\t')

existingquotes =  existingquotes.reindex(existingquotes.index.union(newquotes.index))
existingquotes = existingquotes.fillna(newquotes)

print mergedquotes
```

and leads to the intended result (same as jezrael posted)